# Bitwise shifting operation gives a 32-bit result instead of a 64-bit result in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

When I combine both 32-bit integers it should form a 64-bit long integer, but it stays a 32-bit negative value. What's wrong?

Just this line alone should generate a bigger number than 32 bit: `(readDword() And &HFFFFFFFF) << 32)`

#### VB.NET code for testing

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim u As Long = ((readDword() And &HFFFFFFFF) << 32) Or _
        (readDword2() And &HFFFFFFFF)
End Sub

Function readDword() As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = (((0 And &HFF) << 24) Or _
((0 And &HFF) << 16) Or _
((11 And &HFF) << 8) Or _
(58 And &HFF))
    Return i
End Function

Function readDword2() As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = (((241 And &HFF) << 24) Or _
((145 And &HFF) << 16) Or _
((136 And &HFF) << 8) Or _
(247 And &HFF))
    Return i
End Function
```

Expected Results
-----------------------------
Input bytes = `0,0,11,58,241,145,136,247`
Result I get = `-242119681`
Expected Result = `12347788855543`
------------------------------

This works properly, but it's backwards so I try to do it with bitwise myself

```
    Dim bytesz() As Byte = New Byte() {247, 136, 145, 241, 58, 11, 0, 0}
    Dim a As Int64 = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytesz, 0)
```

#### How bytes are written in Java

```
  public void writeQWord(long l) throws IOException {
    write((int) (l >> 56)); //0
    write((int) (l >> 48)); //0
    write((int) (l >> 40)); //11
    write((int) (l >> 32)); //58
    write((int) (l >> 24)); //241
    write((int) (l >> 16)); //145
    write((int) (l >> 8));  //136
    write((int) (l));   }   //247
```

**FIXED**

Proper code is:

```
Public Function ReadQWord() As Long
    Return (CLng(ReadDWord() And &HFFFFFFFFL) << 32) Or CLng(ReadDWord() And &HFFFFFFFFL)
End Function
```

Comment: The functions and the constants you use are all 32 bit integers. Would change the result type of readDWord to Long help?

Comment: changing return type to long as well as the variable to long does nothing.

Comment: Oh... sorry then. I don't have a Visual Studio handy, so I can't test here. I thought it might have helped.

Comment: This works properly but it's backwards so I try to do it myself with bitwise `Dim bytesz() As Byte = New Byte() {247, 136, 145, 241, 58, 11, 0, 0}`

        `Dim a As Int64 = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytesz, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using bitwise operators and constants make sure that the constant type reflects your usage.

This

```
    Dim u As Long = 1 << 32
```

and this

```
    Dim u As Long = 1L << 32
```

produce different results.  I also notice that your function readDword is only producing an integer both as a return and internally.